# How can I get $magics to support async?

Tags: javascript, htmx, alpine.js

A much admired feature of [HTMX](https://htmx.org/) among beginners is it's ability to abstract away javascript and make fetch requests from the backend directly in markup.

I don't like HTMX because I think it's really limiting, I love Alpine and don't like using multiple frameworks - but I *would* like the ability to on occasion just do a simple request of my backend in order to populate an item in my dom from within Alpine without specifically calling a function to do that.

I have built this functionality using a simple function I have called xfetch in the below example, which is simply passed a url and returns the relevant item into the x-text, x-html or variable in x-data. It can be used in alpine as follows:

```
<div x-data>
    <span x-text="await xfetch("url")>
</div>
```

I think implementing this in a straightforward way, without getting into the details of promises, etc, would be really helpful for beginners getting started with Alpine as their first JS framework.

Ideally I would make this an Alpine magic called `$fetch` but I can't work out how to make magics work nicely with async and await.

My current code is as follows:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script defer src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div x-data="{ time: xfetch('http://date.jsontest.com', method = 'GET', jsonItem='time') }">

    <p>
        This pulls the time from an object in x-data:
        <span x-text="await time"></span>
    </p>

    <p>
        ... but you can also pass a url right into the x-text:
        <span x-text="await xfetch('http://date.jsontest.com', method = 'GET', jsonItem='date')"> </span>
    </p>
</div>


<script>

    async function xfetch(url, method='GET', jsonItem=null) {

        return fetch(url, {
            method: method,
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            return responseJson[jsonItem]
        });

    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Ideally I would add in:

```
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {

    Alpine.magic('fetch', () => url => {
        return await xfetch(url, method='GET', jsonItem=null)
    })

})
```

but this doesn't work I think because the async isn't working when I put it in a $magic.

Two questions:

1. Is it possible for a magic function to run an await the result of an async command?
2. Is it possible to pass multiple variables to a $magic function?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Super was able to work through this. it appears the missing piece was to `return await response`. original answer here did not quite go "all of the way down". updated...

---

1. I believe what you need here is async "all of the way down". I could not definitively test your example as I got a CORS error requesting the data, but I did test with a local handler here that returns some data and I did get my result.
2. I changed your arrow function to a standard function and added a second function arg.

I would also note that [HTMX has ajax](https://htmx.org/api/#ajax) functionality that handles and resolves the async Promise results for you.

For your example, perhaps try something like this

```
 <script>
        async function xfetch(url, method = 'GET', jsonItem = null) {
            let response=
           await  fetch(url, {
                method: method,
            })
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((responseJson) => {
                    return await responseJson[jsonItem];//AWAIT again!
                });
            return await response;//AWAIT again!
        }
        document.addEventListener('alpine:init', async () => {

            Alpine.magic('fetch', async function(url,otherdata) {
                let response = await xfetch(url, method = 'GET', jsonItem = null)
                return await response.text();
            })

        })
    </script>
```

Comment: @super I also wanted to say I had written a fetch wrapping function very much like yours a while back when I was only using Alpine, but now I rarely use to that function in new code since I've adopted a mix of HTMX and Alpine. Both are great libs and each serve a specific purpose and I'm sure each author of those libs agree that they work very well together (or take the plunge and adopt HTMX with Hyperscript, which I may do once it gets to 1.x release). cheers and good luck to you!

Comment: Thank you for this response @pthomson. It now works successfully in running the function async, but only when I don't pass it any variables.

`x-text="await $fetch"` works (so long as I hard code the url)

`x-text="await $fetch('something')"` fails saying "$fetch is not a function"

Codepen: https://codepen.io/hankhank10/pen/wvyVKzr

Comment: Thank you. I got it working in the end - posted the answer here. The final product is here: https://hankhank10.github.io/alpine-fetch/

Answer (score 1):

I got this working in the end, thanks to the assistance of @pthomson getting me half way there

```
// Alpine listeners
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', async () => {

    Alpine.magic('now', () => {
        return (new Date).toLocaleTimeString()
    })

    Alpine.magic('fetchjson', () => {
        return async (
            url,
            jsonItem = null,
            method = "GET"
        ) => {
            let response = await xfetch(url = url, jsonItem = jsonItem, method = method)
            return await response;
        }
    })

    Alpine.magic('fetch', () => {
        return async (
            url,
            method = "GET"
        ) => {
            let response = await xfetch(url = url, jsonItem = null, method = method)
            return await response;
        }
    })

})

// Actual fetch function
async function xfetch(url, jsonItem = null, method = 'GET') {

    if (jsonItem == null) {

        return fetch(url, {method: method})
            .then((response) => response.text())
            .then((responseText) => {
                return responseText
            });

    } else {

        return fetch(url, {method: method})
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                return responseJson[jsonItem]
            });

    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for posting this solution! This answer is useful. so return an async function that contains{ response=await xfetch and then return AWAIT response }